# Power series with finite 1-order poles has bounded generating sequence.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let the radius of convergence of $f(z)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nz^n$ be 1, and $f$ has some poles $z_1$, $z_2$, ..., $z_m$ on $\partial B(0,1)$ with order 1 each. $f$ has no singularities elsewhere on the boundary. Show that $\{a_n\}$ is bounded.

---

I do not know exactly how to associate the condition given in the problem with that the sequence is bounded, which is to prove. I wanna get some ideas, thank you!

Comment: So we can assume $f$ is holomorphic in some $D(0,R)$ minus the poles with $R>1?$

Comment: @zhw. Could you please explain it more explicitly? I can only understand that $f$ can be extended almost everywhere on the circle.

Comment: Is $f$ holomorphic in $D(0,R)\setminus \{z_1,\dots, z_m\}$ for some $R>1?$